# Estimation of $\min_{x,y} (N-x^2-y^2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I tried to solve this using this fact:

> $N'$ is represented as a sum of squares if and only if $2 \mid \nu_{p}(N') $, where $ p\equiv3 \pmod 4$ and $p \mid N'$.

Now we know that $\pi(n) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$
And I thought about finding the closest $p^k$ which is represented as a sum of squares.

So I am interested in some papers to read about this.

Comment: Estimating the largest gap between numbers of the form $x^2+y^2$ is a difficult open problem.

Comment: @GHfromMO I interested in distance between N and number K , which could be represented as sum of squares.

Comment: @openspace: Yes, and this is equivalent to studying the largest gap between numbers of the form $x^2+y^2$. As I said, this is a difficult open problem. It is easy to see that $\min_{x,y}|N-x^2-y^2|\ll N^{1/4}$, and this might be the best known bound.

Comment: @GHfromMO why $N^{1/4}$?

Comment: @openspace: Choose $x$ so that $|N-x^2|$ is minimal. Then $|N-x^2|\ll N^{1/2}$. Now choose $y$ so that $|N-x^2-y^2|$ is minimal. Then $|N-x^2-y^2|\ll |N-x^2|^{1/2}\ll N^{1/4}$.

Comment: My previous comment needs to be fixed. Choose $x\in\mathbb{N}$ to be maximal so that $x^2\leq N$. Then $0\leq N-x^2\ll N^{1/2}$. Now choose $y\in\mathbb{N}$ to be maximal so that $y^2\leq N-x^2$. Then $0\leq N-x^2-y^2\ll(N-x^2)^{1/2}\ll N^{1/4}$. So in the end we found $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $|N-x^2-y^2|\ll N^{1/4}$.